# JSON string has no quotes in response

Tags: java, json, jackson

i am using Netbeans and have built a rest webservice that returns JSON and i am seeing something that looks odd to me... in my response object the externalid field has no quotes but in the model that is being converted here it is a string...

```
"apiName":"Test Case","duration":7644,"externalId":1234561019
```

if the externalId field has a letter in it, it comes up with quotes, but why is it treating the field like a number just because it happens to be a valid one when i have declared it a string?

Should have mentioned my maven imports are the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20140107</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks for any clues

Comment: the actual object is huge, the JSON is valid and has brackets, i just added a snippet... my webservice is built in java... this is the only field that shows up like this but really it should always have quotes around it like apiName, just because it is a valid number doesn't mean it is a number

Comment: show us the part of code, which is reponsible for converting it to JSON.

Comment: netbeans converts the models on it's own when you setup a REST Facade and set the return type to JSON with annotation... @Produces("application/json") before the getTestCase method type thing..

Comment: The only way i could solve this was by using Jackson and calling the mapper.writeValueAsString(response) and returning the string instead of the object.. that got rid of the implicit cast to number